# Photoshop like Magic Wand for selecting pixels of a similar color, but in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, pixel, threshold

Im a noob.

I need to write some vb.net code that looks at a picture and "removes" the blackish pixels.

Here's the scenario. A wound care doctor takes a picture of a persons hand on a flat bed scanner. The nice pink palm print is there but it is surrounded by blackish pictures. I want to make the picture pop by programatically "removing" or recoloring the pixels that are in the blackish range. i.e. the Photoshop magic wand select and delete.

I have not code to start off. Hoping for some reference code and not just pcode.
Searching stackoverflow, I have not yet found an answer.
Got ideas? Please discuss and many thanks for considering..

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to the [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm, that finds a zone of similar colors in a picture, and replaces all the pixels in that zone into a different color (like paint does).

You just need to define a threshold, and instead of painting the pixels, keep track of them without doing any modification.

Here are some Flood Fill questions in SO that might help:

- [Different Methods of Performing FloodFill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914646/different-methods-of-performing-floodfill)
- [Flood Fill Algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367226/flood-fill-algorithms)
- [QuickFill/flood fill algorithm in C#/VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230764/quickfill-flood-fill-algorithm-in-c-vb-net)